# i have an issue while running speechRecognition in python and getting this error - in Linux

Tags: python, linux, speech-recognition

While running the program i am getting this message in the  output.

```
with sr.Microphone() as source:  # microphone as source
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    r.pause_threshold = 1
    try:
        # listen for the audio via source
        audio = r.listen(source)

    except sr.WaitTimeoutError:
        print('timeOut Relistening')
try:
    # orders = str(input('Command : '))  # input in the typing format
    orders = r.recognize_google(
        audio)  # convert audio to text
    print('orders : ', orders)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    return "None"
return orders.lower()
```

**getting this error below :**

```
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:638:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1075:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pcm_a52.c:823:(_snd_pcm_a52_open) a52 is only for playback
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1075:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
```

i dont know how to solve this...

Comment: it shows some problem with sound card. `sr` has function `sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names()` to list all avaliable devices and then you may see if you use correct device - and use correct with `Microphone(...number...)`

Comment: i tried this but issue still persist

Comment: do you have problem with microphone in other programs ? It can be problem with system and I can't help. You will have to ask Google for this error.